# Insert date and time into timestamp in oracle 10g sql plus

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am having an error with my insert statements for a table
The attributes `E_STIME AMD E_FTIME` are the start date, start time and the finish date, finish time of an event. The datatypes for both are `TIMESTAMP (6)`.

I am trying to insert data into the table already created in sql plus on oracle 10g but im getting an error

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

```
INSERT INTO EVENT (E_ID, E_NAME, E_STIME, E_FTIME, E_COST, ET_ET_ID, V_V_ID, C_C_ID)
VALUES ('E000002', 'RAVISINGH PARTY', TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-11 13:00:00.00',
        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-11 18:00:00.00',
        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'4897.00','ET002','V0002','C0002');
```

It was initially giving an error -

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

after adding the `TO_TIMESTAMP` bit in the insert I got `ORA-01830`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The format mask you included only has information down the seconds place, but you included fractional second data in your timestamp.  So you should use the mask suggested by @JSapkota

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following date format to convert to timestamp.

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-11 18:00:00.00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

[TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm)

Comment: This is an another useful answer